# C# WebBrowser running in windows clients but on the windows server no run

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-forms-designer

The app that I'm developping don't work in windows server with C# webbrowser on the windows services. Only when manually I click to run the program

Someone could I help me with this problem?

Comment: Services can run under different accounts, perhaps it is configured with an account that has no network access. Unfortunately there is no info whatsoever in your question

Comment: The accessies occurs offline in local network, I need to access a printer by its web to obtain counters data. In the first access, the printer web create a token cookie that should be informed together with login and password.
If o navigator no enable cookie, the printer web don't run.
My application running normally in windows client ( win8.1, 7, 10) but in windows server (2012 r2, 2008) no run